# Postgres SQL equivalent of spark window.partition with row_number

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, apache-spark

Basically, what is the postgres equivalent of this spark command

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("department", "state").orderBy(col("salary").desc)
val h = df.withColumn("row", row_number.over(win)).where($"row" === 1).drop("row")
```

So this `ranks` salaries per department for each state and then only takes the first row, giving you the highest salary for each department in each state. How can I do this query in a postgres SQL?

Example: Given

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+
|   Name|Department|Salary|State|
+-------+----------+------+-----+
|  James|     Sales|  3000|   CA|
|Michael|     Sales|  4600|   CA|
| Robert|     Sales|  4100|   MA|
|  Jimmy|     Sales|  5100|   MA|
|  Maria|   Finance|  3000|   CA|
|  Raman|   Finance|  3200|   CA|
|  Scott|   Finance|  3300|   AZ|
|    Jen|   Finance|  3900|   AZ|
|   Mary|   Finance|  2200|   MA|
|   Jeff| Marketing|  3000|   AZ|
|   Rick| Marketing|  2000|   AZ|
|  Momer| Marketing|  1500|   CA|
|    Jun| Marketing|  2500|   CA|
|  Bobby| Marketing|  3100|   CA|
+-------+----------+------+-----+

Running spark Window partition above gives me

scala> h.show
+-------+----------+------+-----+
|   Name|Department|Salary|State|
+-------+----------+------+-----+
|   Mary|   Finance|  2200|   MA|
|  Jimmy|     Sales|  5100|   MA|
|Michael|     Sales|  4600|   CA|
|  Bobby| Marketing|  3100|   CA| // Highest salaries in each department in each state
|    Jen|   Finance|  3900|   AZ|
|  Raman|   Finance|  3200|   CA|
|   Jeff| Marketing|  3000|   AZ|
+-------+----------+------+-----+
```

What is postgres SQL equivalent of the above spark query?

Answer (score 2):

This can be replicated as-is with the same function `row_number` in Postgres. Use `dense_rank` to handle ties and get all of the tied rows (works for any highest 'n' you specify).

```
select * --explicitly select columns needed to drop rnum from the result
from (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by department,state order by salary desc) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t 
where rnum = 1
```

One more *Postgres specific* option is to use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

```
select distinct on (department,state) *
from tbl
order by department,state,salary desc
```